# Is there any good algorithm for multiplying each digit number in array?

Tags: java, algorithm

There are two arrays in java :

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
int[] b = new int[]{4,0,5};
```

Is there any good algorithm for for multiplying each digit number in array?
I mean if I multiply a with b, then result should be like:

```
int[] result => {4,9,9,7,7,0}
```

(because 1234*405 = 499770)
I can only think about elementary school version of multiplying.. but it not only requires me a lot of time and not a effective way in programming.
I want to know a way that calculate array itself, not change it to 'int' variable because I have to treat very very big number over than size of int.
Thanks for you advices in advance :)

- No use "BigInteger"

Comment: Your array is initialized wrong doing '1' is actual the ascii value of the character 1 which is actually the number 49 and so forth.

Comment: What about converting it to BigInteger and back?

Comment: No use "BigInteger"......Why not?

Comment: You could use Karatsuba multiplication to do this. It's not exactly linear, but it's a bit faster than the grade school algorithm.

Comment: Roughly how many digits do you have in your inputs? This will dictate what the best multiplication algorithm is.

Comment: Yes, there is. Do you remember how to multiply by hand? If yes: write that down as Java code.

Comment: The elementary school version seems to be the way to go.  Just don't convert the array to an integer in the meantime.

Comment: @Teepeemm OP has already said they're not happy with the performance of grade school multiplication. Presumably they have a lot of digits and n^2 isn't good enough.

Comment: @Asad The rest of OP's question gave me the impression that he was doing something like converting each array to an integer (possibly via `String`) and then multiplying before converting back to an integer array.